# node proxy error Error: connect ECONNREFUSED

Tags: javascript, node.js, proxy, node-http-proxy

I use reverse proxy from the following module
https://github.com/nodejitsu/node-http-proxy

and I got in err for the following code

```
proxy.on('error', function (err, req, res) {
    res.end('Error occurr'+ err);
});
```

**connect ECONNREFUSED**what does it mean this error and what can be possible solution to it?

I use the

```
proxy = httpProxy.createProxyServer({});

    proxy.web(req, res, {
        target: 'http://' + hostname + ':' + port
    });

    proxy.on('error', function (err, req, res) {
        res.end('Error occurr'+ err);
    });
```

and I need just to proxy calls to new port

Answer (score 14, accepted):

**ECONNREFUSED** means there is no server process listening at the specified port. What `hostname` and `port` are you using? Can you connect directly (without the proxy)?

P.S. Unrelated to ECONNREFUSED, but you should also set changeOrigin in the options passed to proxy.web:

```
proxy.web(req, res, {
    target: 'http://' + hostname + ':' + port,
    changeOrigin: true
});
```

Comment: is there anyway to fix without change origin?