# nodejs - Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:80 with http-proxy module

Tags: javascript, node.js, proxy

I'm using http-proxy npm module to create a proxy server to intercept and mirroring the requests from an app. After starting the server, I will run the app with this command from cli

```
open /Users/dev/Applications/Opey\ Go.app/ --args --proxy-server=127.0.0.1:8080 --ignore-certificate-errors
```

The app will open but what is happening is that I get this error in console

```
Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:80
    at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (node:net:1133:16) {
  errno: -61,
  code: 'ECONNREFUSED',
  syscall: 'connect',
  address: '127.0.0.1',
  port: 80
}
```

How I can fix this?I just want to intercept the app traffic before mirroring it to the requested url.

Comment: this link may help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32979418/node-proxy-error-error-connect-econnrefused

Comment: I saw it but didn't solved the problem. I'm calling my proxy inside the `http.createServer()` of node http module. I've also set the `.listen(8080, '127.0.0.1')`